# use if else within ggplot chunk to change colour palette

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to be able to change the colour palette in ggplot2 boxplots, according to another variable `data_origin`.

This makes my boxplots, complete with legend:

```
library(hrbrthemes)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyverse)

data_origin <- "airborne"
mytitle <- "something more than this"
legend_title <- "some words"
melted <- reshape2::melt(iris)
bp1 <- ggplot(melted, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_ipsum() +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Greens") +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle(mytitle) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scale = "free")
bp1
```

This however drops the legend completely and ignores the `if else`:

```
bp1 <- ggplot(melted, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) + 
      geom_boxplot() +
      theme_ipsum() +
      scale_fill_brewer(legend_title, if (data_origin == "airborne" ) {palette = "Blues"} else {palette = "Greens"}) +
      theme(
        legend.position = "bottom",
        # legend.title = legend_title,
        plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
      ggtitle(mytitle) +
      xlab("") +
      ylab("") +
      facet_wrap(~variable, scale = "free")
    bp1
```

Comment: Try with `palette = if (data_origin == "airborne" ) "Blues" else "Greens"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what @stefan suggested, there are two ways in which you can do this (that I know of). The first is using `ifelse()` (I moved the relevant part to the end):

```r
data_origin <- "airborne"
bp1 <- ggplot(melted, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    # legend.title = legend_title,
    plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle(mytitle) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scale = "free") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(legend_title, palette = ifelse(
    data_origin == "airborne",
    "Blues",
    "Greens"
  ))
bp1
```

[image]

The other one is to build the plot up in two steps:

```r
data_origin <- "not airborne"
bp1 <- ggplot(melted, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_boxplot() +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    # legend.title = legend_title,
    plot.title = element_text(size = 10)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_blank()) +
  ggtitle(mytitle) +
  xlab("") +
  ylab("") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, scale = "free")

if (data_origin == "airborne") {
  bp2 <- bp1 +
    scale_fill_brewer(legend_title, palette = "Blues")
} else {
  bp2 <- bp1 +
    scale_fill_brewer(legend_title, palette = "Greens")
}

bp2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>